# Condensing wide DAX table to de-pivot

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to wrap my head around how DAX transforms data and how I can use it to let me compactly display some data in Power BI.

My `Regional Sales Performance` data looks something like this:

```
+---------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+
| Sales Month   | Northeast Calls Made | Northeast Sales Made | Northeast Revenue | South Calls Made | ... |
+---------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+
| February 2017 |                   15 |                   13 |           3000.00 |               12 | ... |
+---------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+
| March 2017    |                   21 |                    9 |           2000.00 |               30 | ... |
+---------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+
| April 2017    |                    5 |                    5 |           1000.00 |               18 | ... |
+---------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----+
```

Ultimately, after filtering my data down (eg, `Sales Month = "February 2017"`), I want to display it something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+
|            | Northeast | South | Midwest | West |
+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+
| Calls Made |        15 |    12 |     ... |  ... |
+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+
| Sales Made |        13 |   ... |     ... |  ... |
+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+
| Revenue    |   3000.00 |   ... |     ... |  ... |
+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+
```

Since I have a known, static set of regions, my best guess is to create a DAX statement with one `ROW()` per region unioned together:

```
UNION(
    ROW("Region", "Northeast", "Key", "Revenue", "Value", SUM('My Input')[Northeast Revenue], ...),
    ROW("Region", "Northeast", "Key", "Sales",   "Value", SUM('My Input')[Northeast Sales Made], ...),

    ROW("Region", "South",     "Key", "Revenue", "Value", SUM('My Input')[South Revenue], ...),
    ROW("Region", "South",     "Key", "Sales",   "Value", SUM('My Input')[South Sales Made], ...),

    ROW("Region", "Midwest",   "Key", "Revenue", "Value", SUM('My Input')[Midwest Revenue], ...),
    ROW("Region", "Midwest",   "Key", "Sales",   "Value", SUM('My Input')[Midwest Sales Made], ...)
)
```

This more or less works, but it seems terribly unidiomatic, and it doesn't preserve column types. For example, calls and sales made are integers; revenue is a fixed width decimal; other columns might be percentages.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is! There is the 'unpivot' option in the Transform tab of the Query editor. There, you can unpivot your data.

I've created a sample, with your data:

- Unpivot columns
- Split region & type
- Split month & year (although you could use PowerBI build-in Data capabilities)

[image: Result:]

Link to the PBIX, so you can see the steps I took in the query editor. [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/omcemivzarxwsgc/sales%204-8-2017.pbix?dl=0)

Comment: Oh man, that's way easier! But is there a way to maintain my data presentation? For example, keeping Revenue as a currency-formatted decimal? And percentages?